# Execution exit when hit await DownloadStringTaskAsync

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 testcla = new Class1();
        testcla.test();
    }
}

class Class1
{
    public void  test()
    {
        test1();
    }

    public async void test1()
    {
        await test2();
    }

    public async Task<string>  test2()
    {
        WebClient testwc = new WebClient();
        var content = await testwc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("www.yahoo.com");
        return content;
    }
}
```

Hi,
i need wait the DownloadStringTaskAsync finished download the content, however when it execute to the line, it exit without any error.

Kindly advice

Comment: you should first have it as `"http://www.yahoo.com"` for it to be a proper uri, however... yes, you aren't doing anything with the results from test2, what are you expecting it to do? and you're running this in a synchronous process, so the async isn't needed here.

Comment: your `async void test1()` returns immediately even though it starts the task for `test2()`.  Since you aren't forcing the application to await the results, the application exits normally.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch anyway to improve for let it waiting to result ? please advice. Thanks.
Test2 shall pass back the string result to test1 for calculation

Comment: `async Task test1()` and then you can force the task to await once you have it in the synchronous section of your code.

Comment: hanks for the help

Comment: In the general case, you should [avoid `async void`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code. As mentioned by @Dispersia, the url should contain `http`, `https`, `ftp`, etc. 
You code has to wait for the `async` task to finish. For a starter, below description will help you to understand `async`.
Look at `main()` method, it just runs a task and that's all. The `main()` do not depend on any of the value of the result of `async` task, it ends and application is closed. `Async` task i.e. `DownloadStringTaskAsync()` takes much time to complete but by the time result is received from the `WebClient`, `main` method finishes it execution and application closes. Hence you will never see any result.

I have made a change to the `main` function to wait until enter is pressed. Wait for the `DownloadStringTaskAsync` to finish you will see content length in the output window. Then you can press enter key

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Class1 testcla = new Class1();
    testcla.test();

    Console.WriteLine("Wait for async task to finish.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

class Class1
{
    public void test()
    {
        test1();
    }

    public async void test1()
    {
        await test2();
    }

    public async Task<string> test2()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient testwc = new WebClient();
            var content = await testwc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://www.yahoo.com");
            Console.WriteLine("Length of content received: " + content.Length.ToString());
            return content;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Async task done. Press enter to exit.");
        }
    }
}
```